# how to separate the white regions bounded by black in a binary image

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I am working with lung cancer detection in MATLAB. I want to segment the binary image of lung CT scan to fetch the region of interest.

In the picture you can see a white region inside the black region.The black objects signifies the lung and the white region inside black object signifies cancer effected portion of lung. I want to obtain the white region from the image. I want to get the output as only that white region in black background nothing else. How can I achieve this?

[image: input image]

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
% Read in image and convert to BW
BW = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxpOz.jpg')); 

% Invert so that the lung appears white white
BW = ~BW; 

% Create a structuring element. Tune the '2' depending on the size of the gap
se = strel('disk',2); 

% Perform mophological closing
closeBW = imclose(BW,se); 

% Fill the holes
lungBW = imfill(closeBW,'holes'); 

% subtract the lung image from the closed image
cancerBW = (lungBW - closeBW); 

% Display the results
figure; imshow(cancerBW);
```

[Click here for the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fp3X.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have not given code, so I am also answering without code.

You could

- use morpholocical closing operation to get rid of the open channel which connects the white region to the surrounding
- Then look for white holes in each black region (e.g. by doing a blob analysis /threshold operation only on the (masked) region which is black)

Alternatively, you could

- look for convexity defects of contours such as described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html#gsc.tab=0) (This is a python version, but similar functions should be around in matlab)

Comment: Since you are still new to Stackoverflow, maybe you want to read some hints of what to do when answers were helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers   Other than in real life "thank you" in comments is not encouraged, to keep remarks focused on content, but you can vote on many answers and accept one.